# Ceiling fan 3d rotation animation in after effects

Tags: animation

So i had This Fan: [image: this] 
which i converted to this using 3d effect in illustrator :
[image: this]
and then i imported the .ai in after effects and converted the vector layers to shape layers. Now i want to rotate the fan like a real ceiling fan but i cant find a way to do it. Please help me out here. I am new to adobe.

Comment: use After Effects own 3D functionality. This will work way better.

Comment: @dom I tried 3d layer option it showed me 4 fields orientation and x,y,z rotations i tried various combination but it did'nt work out.

Comment: could you be more specific? Maybe add a screenshot of your view in After Effects. Oh and of course you should import the original fan into AE.

Comment: using orientation rotate 90° on the x axis to make it parallel to the ground, and using the individual angle controls rotate around the z axis to make it spin.